# Set Focus on Excel Application

Tags: c#, vsto

How to set focus on Excel Application object in vsto C#
i have been searching for it but didn't have any success

Comment: See if this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/795059/vsto-application-focus) helps. and look at this [link](http://www.add-in-express.com/forum/read.php?FID=1&TID=3616)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
 Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("excel");
 foreach (Process p in processes)
 {
     if (p.MainWindowTitle.Contains(fileName.Substring(fileName.LastIndexOf("/") + 1)))
     {
         SetForegroundWindow(p.MainWindowHandle);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution in my VSTO application is:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool BringWindowToTop(IntPtr hWnd);

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the main excel window.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>An ArbitraryWindow that represents the main excel window.</returns>
    public static ArbitraryWindow GetMainExcelWindow()
    {
        var excelHwnd_IntPtr = new IntPtr(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Hwnd);
        var excelWindow = new ArbitraryWindow(excelHwnd_IntPtr);

        return excelWindow;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Activates the excel window.
    /// </summary>
    public static void ActivateExcelWindow()
    {
        var currentlyActiveForm = Form.ActiveForm;
        //if (currentlyActiveForm != null && currentlyActiveForm.GetType() == typeof(FormProgress)) return;

        var handle = GetMainExcelWindow().Handle;
        BringWindowToTop(handle);
    }
```

Just call "ActivateExcelWindow()" to activate the excel main window.

Regards, 
Jörg