# VSTO Excel AddIn: When Excel Inputbox is called from modal windows form, focus goes to Visual Studio

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I have a windows form in Excel AddIn application. I use ShowDialog() to display the form as a modal window. I need to specify a range address in my application. So, I added a button, which calls Application.InputBox.
The button click event contains the following code

```
       private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Excel.Range myRng;
        Excel.Application app = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
        myRng = app.InputBox("Prompt", "Title", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,Type.Missing, Type.Missing,   8);
        label1.Text = myRng.Address.ToString();
        this.Focus();
    }
```

It works fine. However, I need to hide the windows form when inputbox is active. So I slightly modified the code

```
       private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Excel.Range myRng;
        Excel.Application app = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
        this.Visible = false;
        myRng = app.InputBox("Prompt", "Title", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,Type.Missing, Type.Missing,   8);
        label1.Text = myRng.Address.ToString();
        this.Visible = true;
        this.Focus();
    }
```

Unfortunately, this raises a problem. When I click the button the focus moves to Visual Studio. What am I  doing wrong? How to retain the focus on Excel application at the moment when InputBox opens?

Comment: instead of.Focus call .Activate()

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem. The focus gets lost earlier at the line myRng = app.InputBox()

Comment: Clarification: The problem is somehow connected with the line this.Visible = false; The focus gets lost on the next line, even if I replace InputBox with MessageBox. The problem disappears after I comment out the line this.Visible = false;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me I added this line in the middle as below, and it worked fine.

```
this.Visible = false;
this.BrintToFront();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tested your solution. It works fine for me also and it's concise.

Comment: I just tried this answer but in my case there is a kind of a small flash with the screen: it temporary lost focus to excel and then goes back to it with the input box. So this is not ideal. Don't you have this flickering screen issue ?

Comment: @Tabibito Also it seems to me more logical to use `this.SendToBack();` instead of `BringToFront`. (both are working...). Regarding the flickering effect another information : it only appears the first time the input box is called.

Comment: Yes! I also observed flickering at the first time input box is called. It would be great to get rid of flickering. Any ideas why it happens?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have found the solution. I changed the code within the form class as follows

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Excel.Range myRng;
        Excel.Application app = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;

        string fileName;
        fileName = app.ActiveWorkbook.Name;
        Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("excel");
        foreach (Process p in processes)
        {
            if (p.MainWindowTitle.Contains(fileName.Substring(fileName.LastIndexOf("/") + 1)))
            {
                SetForegroundWindow(p.MainWindowHandle);
            }
        }

        this.Visible = false;

        try
        {
            myRng = app.InputBox("Prompt", "Title", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 8);
        }
        catch
        {
            myRng = null;
        }

        if (myRng != null)
        {
            label1.Text = myRng.Address.ToString();
        }

        this.Visible = true;
        this.Activate();
    }
```

Now it works as required. However, I still wonder why the problem happened and whether there is simpler solution. Please, let me know if you have any ideas.

P.S. This link was helpful: [Set Focus on Excel Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11643037/set-focus-on-excel-application)